# Rails - Active Record validations and mark_for_destruction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I'm running on Rails 3.2.22.5 and I can't find any documentation that states whether or not child objects (that have `mark_for_destruction` set to true) will still have Active Record validations run against them.

Example:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  validates_presence_of :children

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent


 parent = Parent.new
 parent.children << Child.new
 parent.children.first.mark_for_destruction
 parent.save!
```

I would expect the `validates_presence_of` to fail, since the child is `marked_for_destruction`. However, I have seen this validation pass in `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships.

This was apparently a bug in Rails at one point, but I am not clear on what the expectation actually is since it's not documented.
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6812

Comment: Have you tried to subclass the `PresenceValidator` for ActiveRecord, like suggested in the Issue you linked? (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6827/files#diff-42f3cf0d3928bfa4d25100d8de05364a)

Comment: @MrYoshiji I haven't. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm more wondering what Rails' explicit design is for this case. I can't find any documentation regarding the expected behavior.

Comment: As described in the issue you linked, the errors are handled by `ActiveModel::Errors`, but `ActiveRecord` is (in Rails 4) rewriting some of those validators in order to have the proper behavior. So Rails (4) design for this case is that `ActiveRecord` rewrites some validators (`PresenceValidator` being one of them) to take into account the `mark_for_destruction` boolean flag (which is an `ActiveRecord` concern)

Comment: Btw, you might want to update your Rails version to use Rails 4. I know it is easy to say but they fixed a lot of things from 3 to 4. If you have a strong test suite or a small app that can be easily checked, give it a try ;)